# how save value in string variable by Javascript executor in jmeter web sampler

Tags: jmeter

Hi I want to store the value return by below code in JMeter webDriver Sampler . but i am getting error.

String access_token = WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(2))");
WDS.log.info("access_token : " + access_token);

OR

var access_token = WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(2))");
WDS.log.info("access_token : " + access_token);

Both above ways are not working?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to help we need to know the details of the error "you are getting". Also it's unclear what `localStorage.key(2)` object stands for.

Here is an example of getting `se:fkey` value from https://stackoverflow.com website:

[image]

I used default language for WebDriver Sampler: `javascript` and the following piece of code:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
var access_token  = WDS.browser.executeScript('return window.localStorage.getItem("se:fkey")')
WDS.log.info('Got the following value from local storage: ' + access_token)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

And it works just fine:

[image]

If you additionally need to store the value into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) add the following line:

```
WDS.vars.put('access_token', access_token)
```

and you will be able to access the extracted value as `${access_token}` where required.

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: Can we use same code by selecting language as "Java" if i need to login then in that case sendkeys is not working if we "javascript"

Comment: I would suggest using `groovy` because `java` isn't real Java, it's [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) and [you should be using Groovy for scripting since JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/) (or even earlier)